# Python testing: Simulate ImportError

Tags: python, import, mocking, pytest

I have the following code

```
try:
    from foo_fast import bar
except ImportError
    from foo import bar


def some_function(a, b):
    return bar(a, b)
```

I now want to test the two cases where `foo_fast` could be imported and where it couldn't.

Using pytest and pytest-mock, I naturally want to encapsulate the two situations in a pytest fixture, so I thought I would use

```
@pytest.fixture(params=(True, False))
def use_fast(request, mock):

    if not request.param:
        mock.patch("foo_fast.bar", side_effect=ImportError)

    return request.param


def test_foo(use_fast):
    assert some_function(1, 2)
```

However it seems the import statement is only run once before the test starts so I cannot mock the `ImportError`.

How does one mock these `ImportError` cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `monkeypatch.setitem()` to set `sys.modules['foo_fast'] = None`

```
@pytest.fixture(params=(True, False))
def use_fast(request, monkeypatch):
    if not request.param:
        monkeypatch.setitem(sys.modules, 'foo_fast', None)
    return request.param


def test_foo(use_fast):
    assert some_function(1, 2)
```

Note that in Python 2

```
import foo_fast
```

will then rise an `ImportError`, while in Python 3 it raises a `ModuleNotFoundError` (which is a subclass of `ImportError`, so the `try...catch` blocks can remain unchanged)

Answer (score 8):

It is possible with the [mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) library:

```
def test_import_error(self):
    with mock.patch.dict('sys.modules', {'foo_fast.bar': None}):
        # your tests with foo.bar
```

In this case `from foo_fast import bar` will raises `ImportError`.