# pytest: how might I simulate non-availability of a pip-installed module?

Tags: python, installation, import, pip, pytest

I have this module installed by me in my virtual env using `pip install`: `concurrent_log_handler` (best thing since sliced bread, by the way).

I want to create a test which will run the following app code:

```
try:
    from concurrent_log_handler import ConcurrentRotatingFileHandler 
except BaseException as e:
    print(f'e was |{e}|', file=sys.stderr)
```

... and want the framework to find that this module concurrent_log_handler is "not available", and thus print out for the user a suitable message like "you have to run 'pip install concurrent_log_handler'".

The thing is, this is not the same as being present in `sys.modules`: it is only **after** the above code that you find that a key "concurrent_log_handler" is now present in `sys.modules`.

Is there some sort of `dict` somewhere of "modules which have been installed but not yet imported"? If so, I surmise that deleting the key from that `dict` might do the trick...

Comment: Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28346798/python-testing-simulate-importerror) just inserting it into `sys.modules` with `None` as the value will cause an import error for you

Comment: Just tested it and it works, in which case this is a duplicate.  that does look like a useful module, btw; I've got something similar (but not concurrent) I wrote myself for small systems, but I'll definitely keep it in hand next time I need logging on a big system

Comment: Yes, will delete assuming no-one comes up with something else.