# Test for missing import with pytest

Tags: python, pytest

In the `__init__.py`-file of my project I have the following code, for retrieving the current version of the program from the `pyproject.toml`-file:

```
from typing import Any
from importlib import metadata

try:
    import tomllib

    with open("pyproject.toml", "rb") as project_file:
        pyproject: dict[str, Any] = tomllib.load(project_file)
    __version__ = pyproject["tool"]["poetry"]["version"]
except Exception as _:
    __version__: str = metadata.version(__package__ or __name__)
```

This code works fine on Python 3.11 and newer. On older versions, however, `tomllib` does not exist, and therefore the exception should be raised (and the version will be determined by using `metadata`)

When testing on Python 3.11 with `pytest`, is there any way of designing a test to check if that approach of determining the version works both with and without `tomllib`, without having to create a second venv without `tomllib`? I.e. how can I artificially generate the exception, such that I can test both branches without having to switch to different versions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock an import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658043/how-to-mock-an-import)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can monkeypatch `sys.modules`, so `tomllib` is not there (see [Python testing: Simulate ImportError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28346798/python-testing-simulate-importerror))

Here is a curated example:

```py
import sys


def func():
    try:
        import tomllib

        return 1
    except ImportError:
        return 0


def test_with_tomllib():
    assert func() == 1


def test_without_tomllib(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setitem(sys.modules, 'tomllib', None)
    assert func() == 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether it's possible to mock `import` statement. But if you are trying to test logic inside of `try` and `except`, I'd create two functions that have the logic, call them from inside of `try/except` block and test those:

```
from typing import Any
from importlib import metadata

def from_config():
    import tomllib
    with open("pyproject.toml", "rb") as project_file:
        pyproject: dict[str, Any] = tomllib.load(project_file)
    return pyproject["tool"]["poetry"]["version"]

def from_metadata():
    return metadata.version(__package__ or __name__)

try:
    __version__: str = from_config()
except ImportError as _:
    __version__: str = from_metadata()
```

Now you can test `from_config` and `from_metadata` separately without complex mocking.
Sidenote: use a more specific exception in `except`, so you don't miss bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can mock `import` like this

```
def func():
    try:
        import tomllib
    
        with open("pyproject.toml", "rb") as project_file:
            pyproject: dict[str, Any] = tomllib.load(project_file)
        __version__ = pyproject["tool"]["poetry"]["version"]
    except Exception as _:
        #__version__: str = metadata.version(__package__ or __name__)
        __version__ = "0.0.0"
    return __version__

@pytest.fixture()
def import_mocked(monkeypatch):
     _import = builtins.__import__
     def _im(_name, *args):
         if  _name == "tomllib":
             raise ImportError("mock")
         return _import(_name, *args) 
  
     monkeypatch.setattr(builtins, "__import__", MagicMock(side_effect=_im))
     yield
     monkeypatch.setattr(builtins, "__import__", _import)


def test_with_tomlib():
    assert func() != "0.0.0"

def test_without_tomllib(import_mocked):
    assert func() == "0.0.0"
```